# Simple form for in nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a website where a user can create a project. Each project contains several papers. And each paper can be "graded" by submitting a form that asks several questions.

I am trying to display a **simple_form** to show the questions but I am failing to do so.

When I go to: http://0.0.0.0:3000/projects/10/papers/31/answering_questions

I get the following error:

[image: My error]

I know that the correct paper and project are passed in `/answering_questions` because if I write `<%= @paper.title %>`, the correct title of the paper is displayed.

**answering_questions.html.erb**

```
<h1>Answering questions</h1>

<h4>You are answering the questions for the paper:</h4>
<%= @paper.title %>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
      <%= simple_form_for [@project, @paper] do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :question_1, :collection =>["N/A", "No - 0", "Partially - 0.5", "Yes - 1"], label: "Question 1" %>
      <%= f.input :question_2, :collection =>["N/A", "No - 0", "Partially - 0.5", "Yes - 1"], label: "Question 2" %>
      <%= f.input :question_3, :collection =>["N/A", "No - 0", "Partially - 0.5", "Yes - 1"], label: "Question 3" %>
      <%= f.association :project, :as => :hidden, label: "To which project are you adding it?", :input_html => { :value => @project }  %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, label: "Send your review" %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My Routes:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :projects do
    resources :papers do
      member do
        get "answering_questions"
      end
    end
  end
  devise_for :users
  root to: 'pages#home'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: Did you define @project in the `answering_questions` action? Could you please add code of the action?

Comment: Ah thanks! I completely forgot I had to pass the params in my action.
I added this:   
`def answering_questions
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @paper = Paper.new
end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind, I'll convert my comment to the answer.

Looks like you forgot to define `@project` for the `answering_questions` action. Since it equals to nil, `simple_form_for [@project, @paper]` builds `paper_path`, instead of `project_paper_path`.

```
def answering_questions 
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id]) 
  @paper = Paper.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: I have noticed that when I click the submit button in the form `answering_questions.html.erb`, it creates a new entity in my database. It does not update (with the answers) the values of the papers in which I am in. Should I create a `PATCH` in my routes?

Comment: @FBSO, look at the my answer - you should find Paper from `params[:id]`, not create a new one